# How to define a variable that can be either Array or List

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Probably a noob question, but I would like to do something like this within a short script:

```
val s = if ( <some condition> ) Array(...) else List(...)
print(s.length)
```

The thing is that s will be inferred as `Object` since there is no common superclass for `Array` and `List`. Thus the second line gives an error since `Object` has no `length` method.

Thanks in advance!

**Update**

Bah, it's a shame that I cannot accept multiple answers! Thanks for all your help, guys! I'm playing around with Scala quite a while but it seems I still have lot to learn :-)

Comment: I know, it doesn't answer your question, but why would you need to do such differentiation? Perhaps, if you'll give more context, we could workaround this in a way that definition wouldn't be needed. (there is *.to[...]* methods by the way)

Comment: Yeah, I know it's quite strange and I wouldn't encounter it normally :-) I'm smashing someone's benchmark code and would like to include two additional cases, one for Array and one for Lists. I know Either could be a solution, but I also would like to keep it simple to convince him Scala is cool and succinct :-)

Comment: You could use wrapper for `Array` and use `s` as `Seq[T]`: `if (true) Array(1): Seq[Int] else List(1)`. You'll get `res0: Seq[Int] = WrappedArray(1)`.

Comment: Yeah, that was the solution, senia! However, I have some issues with multidimensional arrays, but gonna figure it out based on your comment! Could you please post it as an answer so I can accept it? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fact that arrays are implicitly converted to [ArrayOps](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps) which makes them available as standard collections. Basically all you need to do is to pick a suitable interface common to both `ArrayOps` and `List` and declare it as an explicit type for your variable to trigger the conversion:

```
val s: collection.SeqLike[Int,_] =
  if (condition) Array(1, 2, 3)
  else List(1, 2, 3, 4);
print(s.size)
```

**Update:** For multi-dimensional arrays, you need to trigger the implicit conversions inside as well, because `Array[ArrayOps[X]]` isn't assignable to `Array[Array[X]]` and vice versa:

```
type SL[+A] = SeqLike[A,_]
val s1: SL[SL[Int]] =
  if (x) Array(Array(1, 2, 3): SL[Int]) else List(List(1, 2, 3, 4));
print(s1.size)
```

It's not needed for list, because they're covariant in their type parameter, so they can be used anywhere when one of their superinterfaces is used.

If you're creating arrays yourself from a fixed set of elements, you can create helper functions that return the one of the two possible wrappers (`ArrayOps` and `WrappedArray`). Then you won't need any explicit typing:

```
import scala.collection.mutable._
import scala.reflect.ClassManifest

// Using ArrayOps
def arrayO[A: ClassManifest](xs: A*): ArrayOps[A] = Array(xs : _*);
val s2 =
  if (x) arrayO(arrayO(1, 2), arrayO(3)) else List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4));
println(s2.size)

// UsingWrappedArray
def arrayW[A: ClassManifest](xs: A*): WrappedArray[A] = Array(xs : _*);
val s3 =
  if (x) arrayW(arrayW(1, 2), arrayW(3)) else List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4));
println(s3.size)
```

If you have existing arrays you want to wrap, you need to wrap each level like in

```
val a4 = Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(5, 6));
val s4: SL[SL[Int]] = a.map(x => x: SL[Int])
```

Comment: Seems great! Unfortunately, when I try to use it on 2D seqs like `val s: SeqLike[SeqLike[Int,_]_] = if (...) Array(Array(1)) else List(List(1))` I still get type errors. Could you elaborate how could I calm down the compiler? Thanks!

Comment: @rlegendi I extended the answer.

Comment: Cool, thanks, Petr! I was exactly searching what is listed in your 2nd code block. Thanks for your time again.

Answer (score 4):

You could use wrapper for `Array` and use `s` as `Seq[T]`:

```
scala> val s = if (true) Array(1): Seq[Int] else List(1)
s: Seq[Int] = WrappedArray(1)
```

For multidimensional arrays you could create your own converters like this:

```
implicit class ArrArrWrap[T](a: Array[Array[T]]) extends IndexedSeq[WrappedArray[T]] {
  def length = a.length
  def apply(idx: Int) = a(idx): WrappedArray[T]
}
```

Usage:

```
scala> val s = if (true) Array(Array(1)): Seq[Seq[Int]] else List(List(1))
s: Seq[Seq[Int]] = (WrappedArray(1))
```

The idea of using multidimensional array as multidimensional sequences has a big drawback:

It involves conversion on access to every dimension except last.

```
s(0) // <- conversion here
```

So it can lead to performance issues. It could be better to convert `Array` to `Seq`:

```
scala> val s = if (true) Array(Array(1)).map{ i => i: Seq[Int] }(breakOut) else List(List(1))
s: scala.collection.immutable.Seq[Seq[Int]] = Vector(WrappedArray(1))
```

Comment: Thx senia! Unfortunately, when I try to use it on multidimensional sequences like `val s = if (true) Array(Array(1)): Seq[Seq[Int]] else List(List(1))` I get a type mismatch again. Could you enlighten me how could I generalize it? Thanks!

Comment: @rlegendi: I've updated my answer. I guess it could be generalized to any number of arrays in [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) stile, but it's not worth trying because of performance problems.

Comment: Great, thanks for the great answer, @senia! Also, thanks for pointing out the involved implicit conversion on indexing! I wouldn't recognized it by myself easily I think. Unfortunately I cannot accept 2 answers, and Petr Pudlák came up with a bit easier solution regarding my concrete needs. And thanks for the help again!

Answer (score 2):

I was under the impression that the Scala Iterable trait covers this use case:  http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Iterable
I too am noobish regarding Scala.

Comment: Note that under the cover this involves implicit array to [WrappedArray](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray) wrapping